# Does Angular 2 support referencing assigning controllers from templates as in version 1?

Tags: javascript, angular

I always thought, that it is a great feature of Angular 1, that a developer can write business logic in controller without referencing anything related to markup and rendering.

While reading Angular 2 docs, I've noticed such code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Does it mean, that in Angular 2 it is no longer the case and a developer has to reference a template from business logic?

Answer (score 0):

It's still the case since Angular2 supports binding between the component class and its associated template.

Here is a simple sample:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div (click)="executeProcessing()">Execute</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title:string = 'some title';

  executeProcessing() {
    console.log('some processing');
  }
}
```

See the following link for more details of ttempalte syntax:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: But can you avoid having `template` within your component and instead do something analogous to `ng-controller="..."`?

Comment: You can use the `templateUrl` attribute instead to reference an HTML file.

Comment: Can I avoid both of them?